# How to ensure that the user does not modify what he wants by changing the id of the object supposed to be modified via a form?

Tags: security, web

I have a simple problem and I'm looking for what kind of control I can write on the server side to avoid this case:

Via a form, the user can submit answers to a survey. When sending answers to the server, it therefore transmits the list of answers as well as the id of the survey. But nothing prevents him from modifying the id of the survey to put the answers on another survey... I don't see how to prevent that ?

Comment: If the "attacker" knows the ids of other surveys, what benefit would they gain by sending "answers for survey A to survey B" rather than just "answers to survey B." I agree that Stephen's suggestion of long, random identifiers is a very good design, but if the user knows the IDs for a survey they want to send "invalid" answers to, how would it mean to "stop" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent users from changing the ID.  However, there are ways to make sure that they can't do something nefarious by changing the ID:

- Use long random IDs that are effectively unguessable. Then changing the ID will not submit to a different survey, but show an error.
- Use login authentication and make sure that users have the correct permissions to answer a survey.  That way if they change the ID, they could only answer surveys for which they have permission.
- Serve a token with each survey.  The survey can only be submitted back with a valid token that is tied to the ID (via cryptographic signature or by storing tokens and IDs in a database.)

Comment: Thank you Stephen :) !